# How to get byte-array data from servlet to pdf.js

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, pdf

How can I get this:

```
File file = new File(doneDir + "\\" + batchName + "\\" + fileName);
byte[] by = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
fis.read(by);
fis.close();

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=TheDocument." + "pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(by);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

From my servlet either doGet or doPost to the pdf.js function:

```
var data = (byte array returned from servlet)
PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {});
```

Comment: So your pdf is uploaded to the servlet from browser?

Comment: Nope what actually happens behind the scenes is that the servlet goes into the filesystem and grabs the file.  Essentially the browser tells the servlet where to find the file and the servlet knows what to do from there

Comment: Your code to convert file contents into byte array is fine. So what is your issue?

Comment: I'm wondering how the javascript knows to grab that data being passed from the servlet.  I initiate the doPost with a jquery submit, but how does the javascript know that the data returned from the doPost is supposed to be used in that specific function

Comment: So your javascript sends a post request to the servlet and gets the data. Now what is the JS supposed to do?

Comment: I want the data returned from the servlet to be used in this function here: PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {});

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/), I would say that instead of

```
var data = (byte array returned from servlet)
PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {});
```

I think you should use:

```
PDFJS.getDocument(servlet_url).then(function(pdf) {
   // you can now use *pdf* here
});
```

A servlet that returns a PDF file should be no different to the client than a PDF file on the server, and the example uses `PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(...` so this function obviously takes a URL.